# Keep Getting Weird Alert Message from thunderbird 2.0

Tags: thunderbird, imap

I just added a new email account and all of a sudden I get this message every once in a while.

> The current command did not succeed.
>   The mail server responded: SELECT
>   mailbox does not exist.

I don't know why I am getting this. I setup it up on another computer and I don't seem to get this alert.

I don't know what is causing it. I am assuming it is my new email account but I don't know what about it is causing it.

It also just appears every once in a while. Like I can click "get mail" and it will go through and get my mail. Then I do it again and I get the above message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its something with the folders your using and the folders your server is using. Is this IMAP?

Comment: I setup for IMAP and I just setup through thunderbird and whatever it came with after it setup my account is what I have. I added no new folder to it or anything.